# sum over values in python dict except one

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy, sum

Is there a way to sum over all values in a python dict except one by using a selector in

```
>>> x = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
>>> np.sum(x.values())
6
```

?
My current solution is a loop based one:

```
>>> x = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
>>> y = 0
>>> for i in x:
...     if 'a' != i:
...             y += x[i]
... 
>>> y
5
```

EDIT:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import *
x = dict(a=csr_matrix(np.array([1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]).reshape(3,3)),      b=csr_matrix(np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]).reshape(3,3)), c=csr_matrix(np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]).reshape(3,3)))
y = csr_matrix((3,3))
for i in x: 
    if 'a' != i:
        y = y + x[i]
print y
```

returns `(2, 2)   2.0`

and

```
print np.sum(value for key, value in x.iteritems() if key != 'a')
```

raises

```
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 1446, in sum
    res = _sum_(a)
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 187, in __radd__
    return self.__add__(other)
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 173, in __add__
    raise NotImplementedError('adding a scalar to a CSC or CSR '
NotImplementedError: adding a scalar to a CSC or CSR matrix is not supported
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply an accumulator or initial value for the `sum` method:

```
sum((value for key, value in x.iteritems() if key != 'a'), csr_matrix((3, 3)))
```

Note that this is using the builtin `sum` method.  It's almost identical in effect to your loop-based solution.

Using `np.sum` won't work because `np.sum` doesn't pass the `out` argument, and is anyway designed for dense matrices.

```
np.sum((value for key, value in x.iteritems() if key != 'a'),
       out=csr_matrix((3, 3)))    # doesn't work
```

Answer (score 8):

You could loop over the dict to create a generator for the `sum` method:

```
np.sum(value for key, value in x.iteritems() if key != 'a')
```

Comment: thank you, that works fine for my given example! unfortunately my real dict contains csc_matrices. By applying your code, a `NotImplementedError: adding a scalar to a CSC or CSR matrix is not supported` error is raised. I guess, it is not possible to `np.sum` these matrices. should I post a new not-working example?

Comment: @MillaWell: Yes, please do so.

Comment: Could bypass this issue by `np.sum`ming over a listcomp instead.

Comment: @DSM : what do you mean? should I use a list instead of a dict? that would mean, that I'll need to convert/cast all dicts

Comment: @MillaWell: no, I mean you could simply add brackets and use `np.sum([value for key, value in x.iteritems() if key != 'a'])` instead.  The bracket syntax is a list comprehension instead of a generator expression.

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
np.sum(x.values()) - x['a']
```